# get selected items from select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line in my rails app:

```
<%= select_tag :questionnaire_id, 
options_for_select(@questionnaires_types, @questionnaires_ids),
:multiple => true, :size => 7 %>
```

which works fine.

but when I try to use the multiple values that were selected I get this:

```
questionnaire_id"=>["1687,1688,1689,1690,1691,1724"]
```

instead of this:

```
questionnaire_id"=>["1687", "1688", "1689" ,"1690", "1691", "1724"]
```

i.e. I get 1 item instead of 6 items.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just in case that someone will come to this issue, I found the problem.

It seems to be a bug in rails.

I was using **remote_form_for**, and that gave me the strange behaviour. I tried to change the form to **form_for** instead, and I got an array with 6 items.

Rails, Rails, when will you be like .Net? :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think a `collection_select` would look nice but I cannot help with that since you did not post anything about the model. Maybe try this so that it knows it is a collection:

```
<%= select_tag "questionnaire_ids[]", options_for_select(@questionnaires_types, @questionnaires_ids), :multiple => true, :size => 7 %>
```

Or you could just parse the string you currently receive using `#split`.

Otherwise post a bit more code about the associations between `Questionnaire` and what ever this model is.

Comment: I know that I can split the string. But the behaviour of rails seems strange. I would have expected to get an array with items...

Comment: @NoamB. I believe that's is what the name change equates to `questionnaire_ids[]` tells the form that this is an array right now it assumes you want a single response which will cause the `Array` to join.

Comment: So how do I tell the code to assume that I want an array with seperate items?

Comment: @NoamB. just adding the `[]` at the end should seperate this for you. can you post the generated html if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

According to rails code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/41231ef6c6c6a6e546b69add28f04aafb9e0e952/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L134

The name must end with `[]` to be make sure you receive an array.

```
def select_tag(name, option_tags = nil, options = {})
  option_tags ||= ""
  html_name = (options[:multiple] == true && !name.to_s.ends_with?("[]")) ? "#{name}[]" : name

  if options.delete(:include_blank)
    option_tags = content_tag(:option, '', :value => '').safe_concat(option_tags)
  end

  if prompt = options.delete(:prompt)
    option_tags = content_tag(:option, prompt, :value => '').safe_concat(option_tags)
  end

  content_tag :select, option_tags, { "name" => html_name, "id" => sanitize_to_id(name) }.update(options.stringify_keys)
end
```

So just change it to `questionnaire_ids[]`

Hope that helps.

Comment: The code that I wrote in my question does render it like you wrote. In the html it becomes questionnaire_ids[]. But still I get an array with 1 item instead of 6.